# multiple 3G router devices with same hardcoded IP

Tags: networking, router, routing, dongle

I have three usb 3g routers that make me possible to have internet access through different internet providers. I can use one and it works because I can route traffic through that network interface.

The problem is that devices manufacturer hardcoded their IP adresses, then when I try to connect multiple devices there is a IP conflict and I can reach only 1 device.

I'm using Ubuntu on computer side, and I suspect that 3g routers are using some kind of android because are using the same ip that is hardcoded in some [android framework base files for usb tethering](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-10.1/services/java/com/android/server/connectivity/Tethering.java?source=cc#L110)

Device manufacturer name: LDW93 4G LTE USB

lsusb output:

```
Bus 003 Device 023: ID 05c6:9024 Qualcomm, Inc. Android
Bus 003 Device 024: ID 05c6:9024 Qualcomm, Inc. Android
Bus 003 Device 025: ID 05c6:9024 Qualcomm, Inc. Android
```

Also I tried to list all open ports of 3g router with nmap and only port 80 is open, just for access configuration panel.

Use case: have multiple 3g connexions with different IPs to use as proxies.

NOTE: I can only connect to this devices via USB

Is there any way to route traffic, create vlan or something else to work with multiple devices on the same computer?

[image: network-schema image]

Comment: *"devices manufacturer hardcoded their IP adresses"* what devices?

Comment: usb 3g routers have the same IP and I can't change because it's hardcoded.

Comment: How did you determine they were hardcoded?

Comment: I have tried to change it in the admin panel and there is no option to change this, you can only change dhcp server ip address that is not the same as the router ip (when i do traceroute to dhcp_server_ip it resolves to 192.168.42.129 allways). Also I think this device is using some kind of android inside where uses a hardcoded IP (https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-10.1/services/java/com/android/server/connectivity/Tethering.java?source=cc#L110) for usb connections.

Comment: You do not mention an operating system and what your use case is with these multiple internet connections. Please do provide this information in your question.

Comment: *"usb 3g routers have the same IP and I can't change because it's hardcoded."* that's a statement with zero citation & doesn't answer my question at all. Voting to close as 'needs detail'.

Comment: Edited original post and added more info, thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm **not** a "network pro".*

In your schematic **the link from the computer** (IP) to each of the devices are different, the fact that the devices consider themselves have the same IP should not really matter in any way.

Whatever IP's you have "outside" that shouldn't matter much.

In principle, these *(not syntax/error checked)*:

```
$ sudo ip route add default 192.168.42/24 via interface_name1 metric 100   
$ sudo ip route add default 192.168.42/24 via interface_name2 metric 200  
$ sudo ip route add default 192.168.42/24 via interface_name3 metric 300
```

... will have them be a 'stacked' replacement chain (or whatever you might wish to call it), where `interface_name2` will be used if `...1` is "down" for some reason, and if both 1 and 2 is "down", 3 will be used.
I suspect setting them to the same metric, might not be "good enough" - that might set the interface choice to be random *at best*. *(i.e. i have not tried that! might be in the realm of "undefined")*

To have them be equally much used, you will likely need to look into `load balancing`, which I cannot advice you about.

If DHCP is available in each, **connect one at a time**, *set different IP's if possible*, then set the DHCP IP ranges separated, e.g. matching `192.168.42/27` to allow IP's selected by 5 lowest bits, with a 27 bit netmask (32 IP's, up to 110, 111 for broadcast).

*This is similar to having a mobile router connected to your laptop via wire, set at metric 200, and alternating that with a "preferred" wireless internet sharing from a mobile phone, at metric 100; default routes set for both.*
*Which will lead to: if the phone is sharing, then use it, else the mobile router - no other settings changes required.*